# MPAndroidChart - How to left-align BarChart bars

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have the following code to format an MPAndroidChart BarChart in a dialog:

```
 mChart = (BarChart) compareDialog.findViewById(R.id.bar_chart);

 mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
 mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
 mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
 mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(60);
 mChart.setPinchZoom(false);
 mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

 final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "Arimo-Regular.ttf");

 XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
 xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
 xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
 xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
 xAxis.setTypeface(tf);
 xAxis.setTextSize(16f);
 xAxis.setAxisMinimum(tests.size() - 8.5f);
 xAxis.setLabelCount(8);

 IAxisValueFormatter formatter = new IAxisValueFormatter() {
     @Override
     public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
         int intValue = (int) value;
          return (tests.size() > intValue && intValue >= 0) ? tests.get(intValue) : "";
     }
 };
 xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);

 YAxis yAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
 yAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
 yAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
 yAxis.setTypeface(tf);
 yAxis.setTextSize(16f);
 yAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
 yAxis.setLabelCount(10, false);

 YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
 rightAxis.setEnabled(false);

 Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
 l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
 l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
 l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
 l.setDrawInside(false);
 l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE);
 l.setFormSize(9f);
 l.setTextSize(16f);
 l.setXEntrySpace(4f);
```

For some reason, my bars are right-aligned to the BarChart display when there are fewer than 8 bars (the maximum the chart can display).  I would like them to be aligned to the left instead.  I tried looking for a solution on both Stack Overflow and the official MPAndroidChart GitHub, but there doesn't appear to be any posted solution.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?